# Export AppSync state/config?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-cloudformation, aws-appsync

I've been using CloudFormation to keep my AppSync API in my source control so it's repeatable and checked into the repo. Problem is that if I make a change directly in the AppSync console (because it's faster and more convenient to experiment there before attempting to update the CloudFormation stack), now I need to remember to, and know how to add my changes back to the CloudFormation template. This is particularly cumbersome when dealing with resolvers, since AppSync doesn't have a tab that shows all of your resolvers - you just need to look at each field/query/mutation in the schema and see the resolvers for them one by one.

My question: Is there any way to extract all of an AppSync's configuration, hopefully in CloudFormation form? For example, I want a file that describes by schema, each function, resolver, and data source. That way it's easy to ensure that each component is added back to my CloudFormation template.

Comment: Have you looked into [drift detection feature](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cloudformation-drift-detection/)? I've never used it myself but it seems to be related to you question.

Comment: That's a good tip. Sadly, AppSync is not yet supported in the services included in the drift detection.

Answer (score 2):

This is something customers have asked about in the past, and we will take this as a +1 when prioritizing our future releases.